# Error using ssh-agent with systemd

Tags: ssh, systemd

I have been running a GO binary with no issues from my `home/$user` on a remote machine, however when I add the binary to systemd I get `error creating SSH agent: "SSH agent requested but SSH_AUTH_SOCK not-specified"` My unit file is as follows

```
[Unit]
Description=service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/home/$user/go/src/dir/binary

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the binary directly, you are running in your personal shell environment, where `ssh-agent` is likely running and SSH_AUTH_SOCK has been set for your environment.

When are running it via `systemd`, you are running it as root and the ssh-agent and related environment variables have not been set for your your user.

[Understanding ssh-agent and ssh-add](http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/12/understanding-ssh-agent-and-ssh-add/) has more details.